# Getting duplicate actions when processing in MVC controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, api

So I'm sending an ajax request to my controller for processing.
But when I console.log the message in my ajax done function it shows two results.

The result from console.log is:

```
{"result_code":1,"result_message":"Contact tags deleted","result_output":"json"}
{"result_code":1,"result_message":"Contact tags added","result_output":"json"}
```

This is the ajax request:

```
$('.travelSwitch').click(function () {
        //send ajax request
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("ProcessPreferences", "ManagePreferences")",
            data: {
                //Applies to camping category
                categoryTag: "Travel",
                //send user email for processing
                userEmailAddr: "@userEmailAddr",
                //send remove flag for processing
                removeTag: ($('#field_22Travel:checked').length) ? false : true
            }
        })
        .done(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        })
    });
```

Then the function in my controller to process the ajax request:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessPreferences(string categoryTag, string userEmailAddr, bool removeTag)
    { 
        string applyToTag = "TOPIC: " + categoryTag;
        string emailAddr = userEmailAddr;
        bool removeFlag = removeTag;
        var acs = new Acs("api_key", "api_url");

        Dictionary<string, string> getParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (removeFlag == false) {
            //get parameters
            getParameters.Add("api_action", "contact_tag_add");
            getParameters.Add("api_output", "json");
        }
        else
        {
            //get parameters
            getParameters.Add("api_action", "contact_tag_remove");
            getParameters.Add("api_output", "json");
        }

        //post parameters
        Dictionary<string, string> postParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "email", emailAddr },
            { "tags", applyToTag }
        };

        var response = acs.SendRequest("POST", getParameters, postParameters);

        return Content(response);
    }
```

So when the ajax request is processed, it sends a request to the active campaign api. Then adds or removes a tag based onwether the checkbox is checked or not.

NOTES
the switch is from this implementation: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

An initial ajax request is sent on page load to set the switch to on or off:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("InitPreferences", "ManagePreferences")",
    data: {
        userEmailAddr: "@userEmailAddr",
        apiCallInit: true
    }
})
.done(function (msg) {
    //loop through tags
    for (i in msg.tags) {
        //console.log(msg.tags[i]);
        (msg.tags[i] == "TOPIC: Camping") ? $("#field_22Camping").attr("checked", true) : "";
        (msg.tags[i] == "TOPIC: Hiking") ? $("#field_22Hiking").attr("checked", true) : "";
        (msg.tags[i] == "TOPIC: Travel") ? $("#field_22Travel").attr("checked", true) : "";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out.
With what Wail was saying I used `e.preventDefault();` to stop the event binding more than once.
then because I set the checkbox attributes via javascript I just change their values with javascript.

Here is my updates Code:

```
$('.travelSwitch').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('.travelSwitch input').attr("checked")) {
            var remTag = false;
            $('.travelSwitch input').attr("checked", false);
        }
        else {
            var remTag = true;
            $('.travelSwitch input').attr("checked", true);
        }
        //send ajax request
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("ProcessPreferences", "ManagePreferences")",
            data: {
                //Applies to camping category
                categoryTag: "Travel",
                //send user email for processing
                userEmailAddr: "@userEmailAddr",
                //send remove flag for processing
                removeTag: remTag
            }
        })
        .done(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        })
    });
```

Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the your ajax function is being called twice, and in between the two calls the checkboxes are being unchecked... please verify how many events are subscribed to your element when you are trying to click it, it's more a javascript issue rather than a backend one imo.

Comment: this is the only time the ajax request is sent `$('.travelSwitch').click(function () {});`

Comment: Also see my updates anwser, there is an initail ajax request sent to the api to set the checked attribute based on the api response

Comment: Ill try to make this clearer, what `$('.travelSwitch').click(function() {})` does is telling the browser to execute the function passed as an argument to `.click()` each time `$('.travelSwitch')` is clicked. If the `$('.travelSwitch').click(function() {})` is called many times, the browser will call that function passed as many times this line is executed `$('.travelSwitch').click(function() {})` even if you clicked only once.

Comment: Yeah so if the element .travelSwitch is clicked `function() {}` should only run once. not twice. Which I'm trying to figure out why as I'm not clicking the switch twice.

Comment: I think you are confusing the code to execute with subscription to the event actually: `function () {//ajax}` is the code you want to execute, `$(...).click(....)` is telling the browser to execute something in the click event for that selected element. So if you tell the browser to execute that something more than once in a certain event, it will do so as many times as you demanded it each time the event is called, its like binding many functions to a same event, all these functions will trigger once the event is called. In your case it's like having 2 functions bound to the click.

Comment: figured it out, check out my answer. Thanks for your help.